# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused with Laravel when attempting to write data to the database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, laravel

I have been using the [Laravel package for the Wordpress JSON REST API](https://github.com/threesquared/laravel-wp-api) and it works well.  I want to store my blogposts in my database.  I used `phpMyAdmin` to add a table named `idybrand_laravel`

[image]

I created a file `app/blogpost`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class blogpost extends Model
{
    //
}
```

and for now in my `BlogController` I am trying a simple test, wishing to store data in just 3 fields of the table

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use WpApi;

use App\blogpost;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
  public function getPosts()
  {

    foreach (WpApi::posts() as $post) {
      $this->createPost($post);
    }
    //return view('pages.blog', ['active'=>'navBlog'])->with('posts',     WpApi::posts());
  }

  protected function createPost($data)
  {
    $post = new blogpost();
    $post->id = $post['id'];          // integer
    $post->wp_id = $post['id'];      // integer
    $post->link = $post['link'];          //string
    $post->save();

    return $post;
  }

}
```

I have not changed `config/database.php` and my `.env` file looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=idybrand_laravel
DB_USERNAME=idybrand_dave
DB_PASSWORD=myPassword
```

The error I receive is:

`QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: insert into`blogposts`(`id`,`wp_id`,`link`,`updated_at`,`created_at`) values (, , , 2017-02-17 10:21:57, 2017-02-17 10:21:57))`

Do I need to write some code like `init` or `save` inside `app/blogpost`?  Can anybody tell me why the connection is refused?  I'm using `localhost` as my project is in development not production.

**EDIT:**

After some help from the guys in chat including davejal, I am now able to connect to the server BOTH via the command line in OS X:

```
$ mysql -u idybrand_dave -pMY_PASSWORD -h 181.224.130.159 idybrand_laravel
```

AND using [Sequel Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) with no problem.  But I still get the same error in Laravel when trying to connect using those exact same settings in my `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=181.224.130.159 //Siteground IP Address
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=idybrand_laravel
DB_USERNAME=idybrand_dave
DB_PASSWORD=MY_PASSWORD
```

I also tried to edit my model as suggested by Sona but it doesn't help:

```
class blogpost extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'blogposts';
    protected $fillable = array('id', 'wp_id', 'link', 'title', 'author_code', 'content', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
}
```

Can anybody please shed any light on this error?

**FINAL EDIT:**

I had a fundamental misunderstanding in that I thought I could use a localhost 'local' development environment to write data to a table that exists on the server (Siteground) in the 'production' environment.

Once I read the [Laravel Database Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database) and watched [these three](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0AKMvpbMoH0) videos by Mindspace all became clear.  Basically, I needed a server environment running locally and this is provided by [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and [VMWare Fusion](http://store.vmware.com/store/vmwde/en_IE/home).

After setting it up I could access `http://idy.app/` in the browser whilst the `homestead-7 VM` was running and write to the database.

My `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=idy
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I have accepted davejal's answer as it lead me to the solution.

Comment: in blogpost model you need to add fillable columns try this..

Comment: @Sona Cheers - I'll try

Comment: protected $fillable = [ 'fname', 'lname' ];like this.. ad your column names

Comment: and you are doing in local system keep password as empty in env file...

Comment: @Sona I left the password blank and added `protected $fillable = array('id', 'wp_id', 'link', 'title', 'author_code', 'content', 'created_at', 'updated_at');` but got the same error sadly :-(

Comment: keep username as root'

Comment: @Sona `DB_USERNAME=root DB_PASSWORD=` Same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135950/discussion-between-sona-and-dave-chambers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities why your getting this error.

- database server isn't started, check if you can still use your phpmyadmin. If you can still use it then nothing is wrong with your database server.
- wrong config; check username, password and server settings in both your .env file and your config/database.php
- no privileges to the server and or database with given credentials

Looking at the steps you already took I think it's the last.

Check to see if this user has access to the database from the remote location. By default the root user has access to the server locally (localhost,127.0.0.1 and ::1).

So check to see if the user has access from either your remote ip or from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" error message, all I needed to do was change MySQL Port Number in `.env` and `database.php` files to match the one on MAMP

```
DB_PORT=3306
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306')
```

I changed both to the port number configured for MySQL in MAMP.